# Kotlin - Jackson ignore null values

Tags: java, jackson, kotlin

I am getting trouble with parsing JSON with Jackson and I want to ignore null properties. Here is my code.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class ParsedSurvey(
    val items: List<ParsedSurveyItem> = listOf()
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class ParsedSurveyItem(
    val type: String = "",
    val text: String = "",
    val instructions: String = "",
    val prog: String = "",
    val `var`: String = "",
    val columns: List<ParsedSurveyAnswer> = listOf(),
    val rows: List<ParsedSurveyAnswer> = listOf(),
    val num: String = "",
    val multi: Boolean = false,
    val random: Boolean = false,
    val min: Int = -1,
    val max: Int = -1,
    val recordOrder: Boolean = false,
    val rowLength: Int = -1
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class ParsedSurveyAnswer @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES) constructor(
    val text: String = "",
    val prog: String = "<p></p>",
    @JsonProperty("isOpen") val isOpen: Boolean = false
)
```

If I try to set rows property in ParsedSurveyItem to null. I am getting this error:

```
value failed for JSON property rows due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter rows which is a non-nullable type.
Jackson doesn't ignore
```

Why Jackson parses null values? Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens when you use `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` instead of `NON_NULL` ?

Comment: It throws same error. As with NON_NULL

Comment: I usually just make everything nullable when deserializing JSON to not get similar errors, don't know if there's a workaround for that. I believe Jackson uses the default constructor which means it doesn't take into account your default values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set the rows property `null` only if its nullable. It means
change it to

```
 val rows: List<ParsedSurveyAnswer>?
```

You could also remove `listOf()` & `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`